# Passing a parameter through pipe in bash

Tags: git, bash, terminal

I'm trying to pass a parameter through a pipe in terminal for a git command, and, as per usual, I don't know what I'm doing.

Currently: `git rm --cached folder/path | rm -rf folder/path | git commit -m '...'`

I would like to not have to repeat myself with the folder path in the second command if possible, but I'm not sure how to get the `folder/path` from the first command.

Is it even possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Wouldn't `folpath="folder/path"; git rm --cached $folpath | rm -rf $folpath | git commit -m '...'` work?

Comment: I reckon so, but it turns out I can't run the commit command on the same line anyway as it results in a lockfile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do pipe.

```
rm folder/file
git rm !$
git commit -m "your message"
```

Learning the bang (!) operator in bash is very worthwhile. Specifying a long path again isn't the best.

For most of my workflow, I can get away with this:

```
rm path/to/unwanted/file
git add -A # stages ALL changes in the work tree
git commit -m "my message"
```

If I'm fixing up a previous commit which mistakenly added the file that I didn't want, you can amend that commit by changing the last commit in the above code snippet to

```
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

This will reuse the message from the current commit.

You might want to include the output of your git status and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Even though it's not exactly what I wanted to do (again, trying to be a smart arse) it's the better solution to the problem. Thanks very much Adam.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
param=/folder/path; git rm --cached $param | rm -rf $param | git commit -m '...'
```

Edit: @pholser solution makes things a cleaner by removing the variable from the environment with `unset`. This can be done also running the commands in a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html#SUBSHELLSREF):

```
(param=/folder/path; git rm --cached $param | rm -rf $param | git commit -m '...')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=/folder/path && git rm --cached $x | rm -rf $x | git commit -m '...' && unset x
```

Comment: Will `$x` retain the value after the first pipe?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove from the index and remove from the file system separately, `git rm` is designed to do both:

```
git rm -r folder/path
```

There is no sense in piping to `rm` or `git commit` because neither read from standard input in the forms that you are trying. You can just use `;` to separate commands.